# Secure authentication in jboss portal

Tags: authentication, jboss, jboss-portal

I am developing a Portal application and using jboss portal for this purpose. My current application authenticates the user from jboss DB, using the `j_security_check` servlet with username and password as POST parameters.

Now, if I use firebug or any HTTP monitor, then I can see the username and password, which is a security issue.

What is the better and secure way of authentication in jboss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Securing web applications is a vast subject. It entirely depends on your needs.

From your post, what you want (to start with) is a secure communication. You can use SSL with JBoss to ensure a secure channel. I recommend you to take a look at the [JBoss security documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/jbosssecurity/docs/6.0/security_guide/html_single/index.html#JBoss_Security_Model). I am sure you will have more concrete doubts / concerns when you start working with it - then we will try to help :)

I found a very good source of JBoss information [JBoss in Action](http://www.amazon.co.uk/JBoss-Action-Configuring-Application-Server/dp/1933988029/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1319582726&sr=8-1). It refers to JBoss 5 so many areas might be outdated, but other would still apply. I am using JBoss 6 and has been of great help.